# Storing php websocket resource names in array php - how do I access them

Tags: php, phpwebsocket

In my php websocket file, when a new client connects, I am storing the resource name in an array, so I can retrieve it later. Here is the line i'm using to do this:

```
$socketResource = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socketResource, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socketResource, 0, PORT);
socket_listen($socketResource);

//This is an array of user subscriptions
$message_subscriptions = array();
$resources = array();

$clientSocketArray = array($socketResource);
while (true) {
    $newSocketArray = $clientSocketArray;
    socket_select($newSocketArray, $null, $null, 0, 10);

if (in_array($socketResource, $newSocketArray)) {
    $newSocket = socket_accept($socketResource);
    $clientSocketArray[] = $newSocket;

    $header = socket_read($newSocket, 1024);
    $chatHandler->doHandshake($header, $newSocket, HOST_NAME, PORT);

    socket_getpeername($newSocket, $client_ip_address);
    //Store this socket as a resource for later use
    array_push($resources, $socketResource);

    //The file continues.
```

so now, I have `$resources` array that looks like this:

```
array(
    0 => resource id #7
);
```

I also have a different array, which associates a user ID with the position of the resource in that array. When another user sends a message to that user ID, I want the message to (attempt) to send on the websocket associated with `resource id #7`. I want to do this server side so that only the intended user will see the message.

So far i've tried this, but its not working:

```
$resource = $resources[0];

foreach($clientSocketArray as $clientSocket){
    if((string)$clientSocket == $resource){
        @socket_write($clientSocket,$message,$messageLength);
    }
}
```

Is this possible? If it is, how do I go around doing it?

I have already got my javascript code that reads on client side. No problems there.

Thanks.

Comment: where is `$socketResource` declared?

Comment: Edited file, included `$socketResource` declaration

Comment: shouldnt it be `($clientSocketArray as $key => $clientSocket){` ?

Comment: @sietse85, that syntax is not required on here because I only want the value. `$clientSocketArray` is an array with numeric keys, the keys aren't used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the `socket_bind` and `socket_listen` commands. Now, my loop looks like this:

```
foreach($clientSocketArray as $clientSocket)
{
    if((string)$clientSocket == $resource){
        echo "found socket " . (string)$clientSocket;
        @socket_bind($clientSocket, 0, PORT);
        @socket_listen($clientSocket);
        @socket_write($clientSocket,$message,$messageLength);
    }
}
```

I had to do some additional stuff on php-socket.php to make the messages get sent to the right socket name, but this was the underlying issue.